# Why is Socket.io in my React-Native Project only working when the Debugger is running?

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I'm getting started right now with Socket.io in React-Native and I am facing the Problem that the Program is just working when the Debugger is running in the background and so it also works with one Simulator and if the Debugger is running. So the React Simulator only connects with the Server when the Debugger is running.

Code of the React App:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, Text, View} from 'react-native';
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
//import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');

import styles from './styles';

class App extends Component{
  state = {
    name: 'Bob'
  }

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.socket = io('localhost:3000', {jsonp: false});

    this.socket.on('update', () => this.setState({name: 'Sonja'}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Code of the Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.on('update', () => {
      console.log('update');
      io.emit('update')
  });
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "TestSocket",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

So if the Debugger is running in the background everything is working fine, but if i close the Remote Debugger or try the code on 2 different Devices it won't work or just for the one with the Debugger running.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: It could be because the you are using localhost, perhaps use the IP address of the machine where the server is.

Comment: As @Andrew said, change localhost to 192.168.0.2:3000, or whatever your IP address may be. It should say in the terminal and the debugger to what IP your app is running on

Comment: I have tried this, but there is nothing changing...

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io 2.2.0 doesn't work with ReactNative (see https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1254)

It only works in debugger because when debugging, JS is run in Chrome and not in application ReactNative context.

*Solution* => Revert to Socket.io 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade RN to 0.57.x and try to use socket.io-client 2.1.1 or 2.0.4.